# On possiblity to go from state space formulation to an ODE or system of such

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

I seen the canonical way one goes from a nth order ODE to a state space formulation. Is the always a corresponding way back given i.e given any state space model can we find an ODE or system thereof, maybe on some condition on choice of state variables?

Comment: What is the "state space formulation"? The equivalent system of first order? But then this already is an ODE system, so what additional qualities do you expect from the "way back"?

Comment: @LutzL This is the state space formulation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation. I.e of a dynamical system. I think this is more general and I think one such representation is  the corresponding system of first order ODEs given a nth order ODE. But I am not sure that given any "state space" representation of a dynamical system we can find  a collection of nth order equations contaning the same information that this state space representation contain.

Comment: @LutzL is there  a name for the corresponding system of first order ODE given a nth order ODE btw?

Comment: Are you referring to a linear (and time invariant) state space model, or could it be nonlinear and time varying as well?

Comment: @fibonatic linear!

Comment: Sorry but I fail to see how the answer you accepted (after a mere 5+ hours, and  in the absence of every alternative answer), based on the notion of controllability, which is absent from your question and frankly not relevant to it, even addresses your concern? If I may, this looks like a quite **suboptimal** way of using the site and receiving benefits from it...

Comment: FYI, in the present case, it happens one can fully answer the question you asked (and not some other one, related or not), using the notion of [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Comment: @Did you are right, I did do not mention the control theory setting other then by "tag". Thanks for pointing that out and mentioning the companion matrix. I will look into that! Also feel free to post some reference and or explanations.

Comment: My understanding is that you ask to transform a linear differential system $$X'(t)=AX(t)$$ for some $n\times n$ matrix $A$ and $X(t)$ of size $n$, into a single scalar linear ODE $$x^{(n)}(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}a_kx^{(k)}(t)$$ for some function $x(t)$ and numbers $(a_k)$, in such a way that one could reconstruct $X(t)$ from $x(t)$ and its derivatives $x^{(k)}(t)$. Thus, I see no control function $u(t)$ in the picture.

Comment: @Did maybe it is a nonhomogeneous system? I am no expert in control

Comment: If you wish. But all this is clearly pointing at the fact that your question is, in its present form, much too vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you start of with a single input linear time invariant state space model defined as

$$
\dot{x} = A\,x + B\,u \\
y = C\,x + D\,u
$$

then you can write it as one $n$th order ODE if the pair $(A,B)$ in controllable. With $n$ the dimension of $x$. In order to achieve this you have to perform a [similarity transformation](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/SS2SS.html) which brings the state space model into the [controllable canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation#Canonical_realizations). If the state space model has a single input then this transformation $z = T\,x$ can be found with

$$
\vec{v} = \begin{bmatrix}0 & \cdots & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}B & A\,B & \cdots & A^{n-1} B\end{bmatrix}^{-1},
$$

$$
T = \begin{bmatrix}\vec{v} \\ \vec{v}\,A \\ \vdots \\ \vec{v}\,A^{n-1}\end{bmatrix}.
$$

So that

$$
\dot{z} = T\,A\,T^{-1}z + T\,B\,u \\
y = C\,T^{-1}z + D\,u
$$

with

$$
T\,A\,T^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots &  & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
a_1 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & a_n
\end{bmatrix},
$$

$$
T\,B = \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

The new states $z$ can be seen as

$$
z = \begin{bmatrix}z_1 \\ z_2 \\ \vdots \\ z_n\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}z_1 \\ \frac{d}{dt}z_1 \\ \vdots \\ \frac{d^{n-1}}{dt^{n-1}}z_1\end{bmatrix},
$$

so substituting this into the system of linear first order differential equations then its last equation can be seen as a $n$th order differential equation.

PS: I am not sure if in general there also exists such similarity transformation if there are multiple inputs.